# Row.Value returns rounded SHAPE.area and SHAPE.len values?

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net, precision, shape-area

I have created a VB.Net Add-In, and am using IRow to get the value of fields in tables in ArcMap to use in a query.

But I am encountering a problem when getting the values of the `SHAPE.area` and `SHAPE.len` fields. The values returned using `IRow.Value` seem to be rounded from the actual value of the field (the value that would be used to select using the table's Select by Attributes).

So, for example, I can select a polygon using Select by Attributes and the query:

```
SHAPE.area =  50.775141666668361
```

But the following code doesn't work to produce a value to use to successfully query:

```
Dim value As New Double

value = pRow.Value(pRow.Fields.FindField("SHAPE.area"))
```

And it doesn't work because value = `50.7751416666684`

I tried it with value as a Decimal and value as a String. I also wrote the Row.Value directly to notepad without first storing it in a variable, and in all cases the number returned is rounded to two decimals fewer than the actual value.

Is there a way to get the actual, non-rounded, value?

I can use a workaround if I need to, but I'd rather be able to get the actual value of the area and length fields.

Comment: This isn't a GIS query so much as a generic "failure to bracket floating-point comparisons" computer science issue.  If you want a specific row, you should use a rowid query (integer equivalence isn't as flighty as floating-point).

Comment: Just curious, are those units in meters? Even if they're kilometers or miles I can't imagine any GIS-related situation where you'd require that level of precision anyway.

Comment: What confuses me is that two ways to find the value do not produce internally consistent results. The 15-digit precision number is there waiting to be used by ArcMap when I Select by Attributes and Get Unique values, but the Row.Value method doesn't give me that.

Comment: That's because it's not possible to represent that value in an 8-byte IEEE floating point binary.

Comment: ICoursey, you are right in that I don't need that precision (units are in feet), except that when querying the table, if the user wants to use the values in the area or length field, then I need to get those values in order to query. But, yeah, I can just change the query to use a rounded value, which I guess I will have to do.

Comment: You need to use a *pair* of rounded values `Shape.area > 50.7751416666 AND  Shape.area < 50.7751416667` (noting that this gap, in feet, is the size of the radius of a helium atom) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_%28length%29#Atomic_and_cellular

Comment: As a workaround I ended up comparing the desired value against the rounded SHAPE.area value: `Round(SHAPE.area, 5) IN (value, value, value, value, ...)` Acceptable, I suppose, :)

Comment: Just an update in case anyone else stumbles upon this question... That rounding method seemed to work consistently only at certain precision levels. And for some values the query method `Round(SHAPE.area, 13) IN (value)` and `Round(SHAPE.area, 13) = value` actually produced different results. Whether this is an ArcMap issue or a SQL issue, I'm not sure. So I ended up using a comparison method (the first one in the link) recommended by Microsoft to set up the query. It took a bit more to code, but it's reliable.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya2zha7s(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am trying to figure out the same problem. I am at a point where I am writing a procedure for rounding my pairs when i stumbled upon this post. I would be interested to see the code you ended up writing for this. I can't quite picture how the Microsoft recommendation can be used to format the query which i need to construct.

Comment: Jakub, I posted the way I used the comparison method as an answer to this question. Hopefully it clears things up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deal with this seems to be by following the advice Microsoft gives about how to compare two doubles:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya2zha7s(v=vs.110).aspx

Here's how I ended up implementing it in my code for ArcMap:

If I want to select a line based on its `SHAPE.len` value I would set the "where clause" of the query to be:

```
"ABS(SHAPE.len - value) <= ABS(SHAPE.len * .0000000000001)"
```

This would return all the records for which the first 13 decimal places are the same as the first 13 decimal places of `value`.

As stated in the question above, `value` is what is returned from `pRow.Value(pRow.Fields.FindField("SHAPE.len"))`

And this is an issue in ArcMap because that value is not the actual value that ArcMap will be querying against, which is why the double comparison method is necessary.

I found that for all the data I have encountered so far 13 decimal places works perfectly, but I'm not sure if this will always be the case. It might be necessary to reduce the precision, but that's easy to do by taking out some zeros in the query and testing.